# why isn't my cone rotating smoothly when being dragged by mouse

Tags: javascript, frontend, webgl, webgl2

Here is the demo.

```js
// A set of utility functions for /common operations across our application
const utils = {

  // Find and return a DOM element given an ID
  getCanvas(id) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!canvas) {
      console.error(`There is no canvas with id ${id} on this page.`);
      return null;
    }

    return canvas;
  },

  // Given a canvas element, return the WebGL2 context
  getGLContext(canvas) {
    return canvas.getContext('webgl2') || console.error('WebGL2 is not available in your browser.');
  },

  // Given a canvas element, expand it to the size of the window
  // and ensure that it automatically resizes as the window changes
  autoResizeCanvas(canvas) {
    const expandFullScreen = () => {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
    expandFullScreen();
    // Resize screen when the browser has triggered the resize event
    window.addEventListener('resize', expandFullScreen);
  },

  // Given a WebGL context and an id for a shader script,
  // return a compiled shader
  getShader(gl, id) {
    const script = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!script) {
      return null;
    }

    const shaderString = script.text.trim();

    let shader;
    if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-vertex') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-fragment') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderString);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  },

  // Normalize colors from 0-255 to 0-1
  normalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c / 255);
  },

  // De-normalize colors from 0-1 to 0-255
  denormalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c * 255);
  },

  // Returns computed normals for provided vertices.
  // Note: Indices have to be completely defined--NO TRIANGLE_STRIP only TRIANGLES.
  calculateNormals(vs, ind) {
    const
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      z = 2,
      ns = [];

    // For each vertex, initialize normal x, normal y, normal z
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      ns[i + x] = 0.0;
      ns[i + y] = 0.0;
      ns[i + z] = 0.0;
    }

    // We work on triads of vertices to calculate
    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      // Normals so i = i+3 (i = indices index)
      const v1 = [],
        v2 = [],
        normal = [];

      // p2 - p1
      v1[x] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v1[y] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v1[z] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // p0 - p1
      v2[x] = vs[3 * ind[i] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v2[y] = vs[3 * ind[i] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v2[z] = vs[3 * ind[i] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // Cross product by Sarrus Rule
      normal[x] = v1[y] * v2[z] - v1[z] * v2[y];
      normal[y] = v1[z] * v2[x] - v1[x] * v2[z];
      normal[z] = v1[x] * v2[y] - v1[y] * v2[x];

      // Update the normals of that triangle: sum of vectors
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] + normal[x];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] + normal[y];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] + normal[z];
      }
    }

    // Normalize the result.
    // The increment here is because each vertex occurs.
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      // With an offset of 3 in the array (due to x, y, z contiguous values)
      const nn = [];
      nn[x] = ns[i + x];
      nn[y] = ns[i + y];
      nn[z] = ns[i + z];

      let len = Math.sqrt((nn[x] * nn[x]) + (nn[y] * nn[y]) + (nn[z] * nn[z]));
      if (len === 0) len = 1.0;

      nn[x] = nn[x] / len;
      nn[y] = nn[y] / len;
      nn[z] = nn[z] / len;

      ns[i + x] = nn[x];
      ns[i + y] = nn[y];
      ns[i + z] = nn[z];
    }

    return ns;
  },

  // A simpler API on top of the dat.GUI API, specifically
  // designed for this book for a simpler codebase
  configureControls(settings, options = {
    width: 300
  }) {
    // Check if a gui instance is passed in or create one by default
    const gui = options.gui || new dat.GUI(options);
    const state = {};

    const isAction = v => typeof v === 'function';

    const isFolder = v =>
      !isAction(v) &&
      typeof v === 'object' &&
      (v.value === null || v.value === undefined);

    const isColor = v =>
      (typeof v === 'string' && ~v.indexOf('#')) ||
      (Array.isArray(v) && v.length >= 3);

    Object.keys(settings).forEach(key => {
      const settingValue = settings[key];

      if (isAction(settingValue)) {
        state[key] = settingValue;
        return gui.add(state, key);
      }
      if (isFolder(settingValue)) {
        // If it's a folder, recursively call with folder as root settings element
        return utils.configureControls(settingValue, {
          gui: gui.addFolder(key)
        });
      }

      const {
        value,
        min,
        max,
        step,
        options,
        onChange = () => null,
      } = settingValue;

      // set state
      state[key] = value;

      let controller;

      // There are many other values we can set on top of the dat.GUI
      // API, but we'll only need a few for our purposes
      if (options) {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, options);
      } else if (isColor(value)) {
        controller = gui.addColor(state, key)
      } else {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, min, max, step)
      }

      controller.onChange(v => onChange(v, state))
    });
  },

  // Calculate tangets for a given set of vertices
  calculateTangents(vs, tc, ind) {
    const tangents = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length / 3; i++) {
      tangents[i] = [0, 0, 0];
    }

    let
      a = [0, 0, 0],
      b = [0, 0, 0],
      triTangent = [0, 0, 0];

    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      const i0 = ind[i];
      const i1 = ind[i + 1];
      const i2 = ind[i + 2];

      const pos0 = [vs[i0 * 3], vs[i0 * 3 + 1], vs[i0 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos1 = [vs[i1 * 3], vs[i1 * 3 + 1], vs[i1 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos2 = [vs[i2 * 3], vs[i2 * 3 + 1], vs[i2 * 3 + 2]];

      const tex0 = [tc[i0 * 2], tc[i0 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex1 = [tc[i1 * 2], tc[i1 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex2 = [tc[i2 * 2], tc[i2 * 2 + 1]];

      vec3.subtract(a, pos1, pos0);
      vec3.subtract(b, pos2, pos0);

      const c2c1b = tex1[1] - tex0[1];
      const c3c1b = tex2[0] - tex0[1];

      triTangent = [c3c1b * a[0] - c2c1b * b[0], c3c1b * a[1] - c2c1b * b[1], c3c1b * a[2] - c2c1b * b[2]];

      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i0], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i1], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i2], triTangent);
    }

    // Normalize tangents
    const ts = [];
    tangents.forEach(tan => {
      vec3.normalize(tan, tan);
      ts.push(tan[0]);
      ts.push(tan[1]);
      ts.push(tan[2]);
    });

    return ts;
  }

};



let
  gl,
  program,
  modelViewMatrix = mat4.create(),
  projectionMatrix = mat4.create(),
  normalMatrix = mat4.create(),
  vao,
  indices,
  sphereIndicesBuffer,
  currentX,
  currentY,
  lastX,
  lastY,
  dragging,
  rotateAxis = [0, 1, 0],
  angle = 0,
  shininess = 10,
  clearColor = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9],
  lightColor = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  lightAmbient = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 1],
  lightSpecular = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  lightDirection = [-0.25, -0.25, -0.25],
  materialDiffuse = [46 / 256, 99 / 256, 191 / 256, 1],
  materialAmbient = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  materialSpecular = [1, 1, 1, 1];

function initProgram() {
  // Configure `canvas`
  const canvas = utils.getCanvas('webgl-canvas');
  utils.autoResizeCanvas(canvas);

  // Configure `gl`
  gl = utils.getGLContext(canvas);
  gl.clearColor(...clearColor, 1);
  gl.clearDepth(100);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  // Shader source
  const vertexShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'vertex-shader');
  const fragmentShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'fragment-shader');

  // Configure `program`
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error('Could not initialize shaders');
  }

  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Set locations onto `program` instance
  program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexPosition');
  program.aVertexNormal = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexNormal');
  program.uProjectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uProjectionMatrix');
  program.uModelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uModelViewMatrix');
  program.uNormalMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uNormalMatrix');
  program.uMaterialAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialAmbient');
  program.uMaterialDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialDiffuse');
  program.uMaterialSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialSpecular');
  program.uShininess = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uShininess');
  program.uLightAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightAmbient');
  program.uLightDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDiffuse');
  program.uLightSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightSpecular');
  program.uLightDirection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDirection');

  canvas.onmousedown = event => onMouseDown(event);
  canvas.onmouseup = event => onMouseUp(event);
  canvas.onmousemove = event => onMouseMove(event);
}

// Configure lights
function initLights() {
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightDiffuse, lightColor);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightAmbient, lightAmbient);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightSpecular, lightSpecular);
  gl.uniform3fv(program.uLightDirection, lightDirection);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialAmbient, materialAmbient);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialSpecular, materialSpecular);
  gl.uniform1f(program.uShininess, shininess);
}

function initBuffers() {
  const vertices = [
    1.5, 0, 0, -1.5, 1, 0, -1.5, 0.809017, 0.587785, -1.5, 0.309017, 0.951057, -1.5, -0.309017, 0.951057, -1.5, -0.809017, 0.587785, -1.5, -1, 0, -1.5, -0.809017, -0.587785, -1.5, -0.309017, -0.951057, -1.5, 0.309017, -0.951057, -1.5, 0.809017, -0.587785
  ];
  indices = [
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    0, 3, 4,
    0, 4, 5,
    0, 5, 6,
    0, 6, 7,
    0, 7, 8,
    0, 8, 9,
    0, 9, 10,
    0, 10, 1
  ];
  const normals = utils.calculateNormals(vertices, indices);

  // Create VAO
  vao = gl.createVertexArray();

  // Bind VAO
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Vertices
  const sphereVerticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereVerticesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  // Configure VAO instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Normals
  const sphereNormalsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereNormalsBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  // Configure VAO instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexNormal);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Indices
  sphereIndicesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereIndicesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Clean
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  dragging = true;
  currentX = event.clientX;
  currentY = event.clientY;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  if (dragging) {
    lastX = currentX;
    lastY = currentY;

    currentX = event.clientX;
    currentY = event.clientY;

    const dx = currentX - lastX;

    rotateAxis = [0, 1, 0];
    angle = dx;
  }
}

function onMouseUp() {
  dragging = false;
}

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, 45, gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 10000);
  mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [0, 0, -5]);

  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, angle * Math.PI / 180, [0, 1, 0]);

  mat4.copy(normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.invert(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
  mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uNormalMatrix, false, normalMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uModelViewMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uProjectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix);

  // We will start using the `try/catch` to capture any errors from our `draw` calls
  try {
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}


function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  draw();
}

function init() {
  initProgram();
  initBuffers();
  initLights();
  render();

}


init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
  <!-- vertex Shader -->
  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

    in vec3 aVertexPosition;
    in vec3 aVertexNormal;

    out vec3 vNormal;
    out vec3 vEyeVector;

    void main(void) {
      vec4 vertex = uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
      // Set varyings to be used inside of fragment shader
      vNormal = vec3(uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0));
      vEyeVector = -vec3(vertex.xyz);
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- fragment Shader -->
  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    uniform float uShininess;
    uniform vec3 uLightDirection;
    uniform vec4 uLightAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uLightDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uLightSpecular;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialSpecular;

    in vec3 vNormal;
    in vec3 vEyeVector;

    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main(void) {
      // Normalized light direction
      vec3 L = normalize(uLightDirection);

      // Normalized normal
      vec3 N = normalize(vNormal);

      float lambertTerm = dot(N, -L);
      // Ambient
      vec4 Ia = uLightAmbient * uMaterialAmbient;
      // Diffuse
      vec4 Id = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      // Specular
      vec4 Is = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

      if (lambertTerm > 0.0) {
        Id = uLightDiffuse * uMaterialDiffuse * lambertTerm;
        vec3 E = normalize(vEyeVector);
        vec3 R = reflect(L, N);
        float specular = pow( max(dot(R, E), 0.0), uShininess);
        Is = uLightSpecular * uMaterialSpecular * specular;
      }

      // Final fargment color takes into account all light values that
      // were computed within the fragment shader
      fragColor = vec4(vec3(Ia + Id + Is), 1.0);
    }
  </script>
  <canvas id="webgl-canvas">  </canvas>
```

The thing I wanted to achieve was, I wanted to use my mouse to drag this cone and rotate it around y axis.

so first I have my canvas events set up.

```
canvas.onmousedown = event => onMouseDown(event);
canvas.onmouseup = event => onMouseUp(event);
canvas.onmousemove = event => onMouseMove(event);
...
function onMouseDown(event) {
    dragging = true;
    currentX = event.clientX;
    currentY = event.clientY;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    if(dragging) {
        lastX = currentX;
        lastY = currentY;

        currentX = event.clientX;
        currentY = event.clientY;

        const dx = currentX - lastX;

        rotateAxis = [0,1,0];
        angle = dx;
    }
}

function onMouseUp() {
    dragging = false;
}
```

The logic is, when the mouse is pressed, I set the flag `dragging` to be true and store the screen coordinates to `currentX` and `currentY`, then moving the mouse, I will calculate the difference between the current coordinates and the previous coordinates and increase or decrease the rotation angle. And then the mouse is not pressed, i.e. it is up, I set the flag to be false.

The problem I have is, even though it works, but it kinda have this not-smooth feel to it. Can someone please help me improve it?

Comment: FYI: you can use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for code on Stack Overflow. Also it's nice to separate the JS/CSS/HTML parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is:

`angle += dx;`, as you want to accumulate the rotation deltas. Currently you just overwrite the angle with latest dx.

Updated example below:

```js
// A set of utility functions for /common operations across our application
const utils = {

  // Find and return a DOM element given an ID
  getCanvas(id) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!canvas) {
      console.error(`There is no canvas with id ${id} on this page.`);
      return null;
    }

    return canvas;
  },

  // Given a canvas element, return the WebGL2 context
  getGLContext(canvas) {
    return canvas.getContext('webgl2') || console.error('WebGL2 is not available in your browser.');
  },

  // Given a canvas element, expand it to the size of the window
  // and ensure that it automatically resizes as the window changes
  autoResizeCanvas(canvas) {
    const expandFullScreen = () => {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
    expandFullScreen();
    // Resize screen when the browser has triggered the resize event
    window.addEventListener('resize', expandFullScreen);
  },

  // Given a WebGL context and an id for a shader script,
  // return a compiled shader
  getShader(gl, id) {
    const script = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!script) {
      return null;
    }

    const shaderString = script.text.trim();

    let shader;
    if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-vertex') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-fragment') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderString);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  },

  // Normalize colors from 0-255 to 0-1
  normalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c / 255);
  },

  // De-normalize colors from 0-1 to 0-255
  denormalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c * 255);
  },

  // Returns computed normals for provided vertices.
  // Note: Indices have to be completely defined--NO TRIANGLE_STRIP only TRIANGLES.
  calculateNormals(vs, ind) {
    const
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      z = 2,
      ns = [];

    // For each vertex, initialize normal x, normal y, normal z
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      ns[i + x] = 0.0;
      ns[i + y] = 0.0;
      ns[i + z] = 0.0;
    }

    // We work on triads of vertices to calculate
    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      // Normals so i = i+3 (i = indices index)
      const v1 = [],
        v2 = [],
        normal = [];

      // p2 - p1
      v1[x] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v1[y] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v1[z] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // p0 - p1
      v2[x] = vs[3 * ind[i] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v2[y] = vs[3 * ind[i] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v2[z] = vs[3 * ind[i] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // Cross product by Sarrus Rule
      normal[x] = v1[y] * v2[z] - v1[z] * v2[y];
      normal[y] = v1[z] * v2[x] - v1[x] * v2[z];
      normal[z] = v1[x] * v2[y] - v1[y] * v2[x];

      // Update the normals of that triangle: sum of vectors
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] + normal[x];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] + normal[y];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] + normal[z];
      }
    }

    // Normalize the result.
    // The increment here is because each vertex occurs.
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      // With an offset of 3 in the array (due to x, y, z contiguous values)
      const nn = [];
      nn[x] = ns[i + x];
      nn[y] = ns[i + y];
      nn[z] = ns[i + z];

      let len = Math.sqrt((nn[x] * nn[x]) + (nn[y] * nn[y]) + (nn[z] * nn[z]));
      if (len === 0) len = 1.0;

      nn[x] = nn[x] / len;
      nn[y] = nn[y] / len;
      nn[z] = nn[z] / len;

      ns[i + x] = nn[x];
      ns[i + y] = nn[y];
      ns[i + z] = nn[z];
    }

    return ns;
  },

  // A simpler API on top of the dat.GUI API, specifically
  // designed for this book for a simpler codebase
  configureControls(settings, options = {
    width: 300
  }) {
    // Check if a gui instance is passed in or create one by default
    const gui = options.gui || new dat.GUI(options);
    const state = {};

    const isAction = v => typeof v === 'function';

    const isFolder = v =>
      !isAction(v) &&
      typeof v === 'object' &&
      (v.value === null || v.value === undefined);

    const isColor = v =>
      (typeof v === 'string' && ~v.indexOf('#')) ||
      (Array.isArray(v) && v.length >= 3);

    Object.keys(settings).forEach(key => {
      const settingValue = settings[key];

      if (isAction(settingValue)) {
        state[key] = settingValue;
        return gui.add(state, key);
      }
      if (isFolder(settingValue)) {
        // If it's a folder, recursively call with folder as root settings element
        return utils.configureControls(settingValue, {
          gui: gui.addFolder(key)
        });
      }

      const {
        value,
        min,
        max,
        step,
        options,
        onChange = () => null,
      } = settingValue;

      // set state
      state[key] = value;

      let controller;

      // There are many other values we can set on top of the dat.GUI
      // API, but we'll only need a few for our purposes
      if (options) {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, options);
      } else if (isColor(value)) {
        controller = gui.addColor(state, key)
      } else {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, min, max, step)
      }

      controller.onChange(v => onChange(v, state))
    });
  },

  // Calculate tangets for a given set of vertices
  calculateTangents(vs, tc, ind) {
    const tangents = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length / 3; i++) {
      tangents[i] = [0, 0, 0];
    }

    let
      a = [0, 0, 0],
      b = [0, 0, 0],
      triTangent = [0, 0, 0];

    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      const i0 = ind[i];
      const i1 = ind[i + 1];
      const i2 = ind[i + 2];

      const pos0 = [vs[i0 * 3], vs[i0 * 3 + 1], vs[i0 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos1 = [vs[i1 * 3], vs[i1 * 3 + 1], vs[i1 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos2 = [vs[i2 * 3], vs[i2 * 3 + 1], vs[i2 * 3 + 2]];

      const tex0 = [tc[i0 * 2], tc[i0 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex1 = [tc[i1 * 2], tc[i1 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex2 = [tc[i2 * 2], tc[i2 * 2 + 1]];

      vec3.subtract(a, pos1, pos0);
      vec3.subtract(b, pos2, pos0);

      const c2c1b = tex1[1] - tex0[1];
      const c3c1b = tex2[0] - tex0[1];

      triTangent = [c3c1b * a[0] - c2c1b * b[0], c3c1b * a[1] - c2c1b * b[1], c3c1b * a[2] - c2c1b * b[2]];

      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i0], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i1], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i2], triTangent);
    }

    // Normalize tangents
    const ts = [];
    tangents.forEach(tan => {
      vec3.normalize(tan, tan);
      ts.push(tan[0]);
      ts.push(tan[1]);
      ts.push(tan[2]);
    });

    return ts;
  }

};



let
  gl,
  program,
  modelViewMatrix = mat4.create(),
  projectionMatrix = mat4.create(),
  normalMatrix = mat4.create(),
  vao,
  indices,
  sphereIndicesBuffer,
  currentX,
  currentY,
  lastX,
  lastY,
  dragging,
  rotateAxis = [0, 1, 0],
  angle = 0,
  shininess = 10,
  clearColor = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9],
  lightColor = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  lightAmbient = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 1],
  lightSpecular = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  lightDirection = [-0.25, -0.25, -0.25],
  materialDiffuse = [46 / 256, 99 / 256, 191 / 256, 1],
  materialAmbient = [1, 1, 1, 1],
  materialSpecular = [1, 1, 1, 1];

function initProgram() {
  // Configure `canvas`
  const canvas = utils.getCanvas('webgl-canvas');
  utils.autoResizeCanvas(canvas);

  // Configure `gl`
  gl = utils.getGLContext(canvas);
  gl.clearColor(...clearColor, 1);
  gl.clearDepth(100);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  // Shader source
  const vertexShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'vertex-shader');
  const fragmentShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'fragment-shader');

  // Configure `program`
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error('Could not initialize shaders');
  }

  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Set locations onto `program` instance
  program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexPosition');
  program.aVertexNormal = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexNormal');
  program.uProjectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uProjectionMatrix');
  program.uModelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uModelViewMatrix');
  program.uNormalMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uNormalMatrix');
  program.uMaterialAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialAmbient');
  program.uMaterialDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialDiffuse');
  program.uMaterialSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialSpecular');
  program.uShininess = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uShininess');
  program.uLightAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightAmbient');
  program.uLightDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDiffuse');
  program.uLightSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightSpecular');
  program.uLightDirection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDirection');

  canvas.onmousedown = event => onMouseDown(event);
  canvas.onmouseup = event => onMouseUp(event);
  canvas.onmousemove = event => onMouseMove(event);
}

// Configure lights
function initLights() {
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightDiffuse, lightColor);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightAmbient, lightAmbient);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightSpecular, lightSpecular);
  gl.uniform3fv(program.uLightDirection, lightDirection);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialAmbient, materialAmbient);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uMaterialSpecular, materialSpecular);
  gl.uniform1f(program.uShininess, shininess);
}

function initBuffers() {
  const vertices = [
    1.5, 0, 0, -1.5, 1, 0, -1.5, 0.809017, 0.587785, -1.5, 0.309017, 0.951057, -1.5, -0.309017, 0.951057, -1.5, -0.809017, 0.587785, -1.5, -1, 0, -1.5, -0.809017, -0.587785, -1.5, -0.309017, -0.951057, -1.5, 0.309017, -0.951057, -1.5, 0.809017, -0.587785
  ];
  indices = [
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    0, 3, 4,
    0, 4, 5,
    0, 5, 6,
    0, 6, 7,
    0, 7, 8,
    0, 8, 9,
    0, 9, 10,
    0, 10, 1
  ];
  const normals = utils.calculateNormals(vertices, indices);

  // Create VAO
  vao = gl.createVertexArray();

  // Bind VAO
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Vertices
  const sphereVerticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereVerticesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  // Configure VAO instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Normals
  const sphereNormalsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereNormalsBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  // Configure VAO instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexNormal);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Indices
  sphereIndicesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereIndicesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Clean
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  dragging = true;
  currentX = event.clientX;
  currentY = event.clientY;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  if (dragging) {
    lastX = currentX;
    lastY = currentY;

    currentX = event.clientX;
    currentY = event.clientY;

    const dx = currentX - lastX;

    rotateAxis = [0, 1, 0];
    angle += dx;
  }
}

function onMouseUp() {
  dragging = false;
}

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, 45, gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 10000);
  mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [0, 0, -5]);

  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, angle * Math.PI / 180, [0, 1, 0]);

  mat4.copy(normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.invert(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
  mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uNormalMatrix, false, normalMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uModelViewMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uProjectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix);

  // We will start using the `try/catch` to capture any errors from our `draw` calls
  try {
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}


function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  draw();
}

function init() {
  initProgram();
  initBuffers();
  initLights();
  render();

}


init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
  <!-- vertex Shader -->
  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

    in vec3 aVertexPosition;
    in vec3 aVertexNormal;

    out vec3 vNormal;
    out vec3 vEyeVector;

    void main(void) {
      vec4 vertex = uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
      // Set varyings to be used inside of fragment shader
      vNormal = vec3(uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0));
      vEyeVector = -vec3(vertex.xyz);
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- fragment Shader -->
  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    uniform float uShininess;
    uniform vec3 uLightDirection;
    uniform vec4 uLightAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uLightDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uLightSpecular;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialSpecular;

    in vec3 vNormal;
    in vec3 vEyeVector;

    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main(void) {
      // Normalized light direction
      vec3 L = normalize(uLightDirection);

      // Normalized normal
      vec3 N = normalize(vNormal);

      float lambertTerm = dot(N, -L);
      // Ambient
      vec4 Ia = uLightAmbient * uMaterialAmbient;
      // Diffuse
      vec4 Id = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      // Specular
      vec4 Is = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

      if (lambertTerm > 0.0) {
        Id = uLightDiffuse * uMaterialDiffuse * lambertTerm;
        vec3 E = normalize(vEyeVector);
        vec3 R = reflect(L, N);
        float specular = pow( max(dot(R, E), 0.0), uShininess);
        Is = uLightSpecular * uMaterialSpecular * specular;
      }

      // Final fargment color takes into account all light values that
      // were computed within the fragment shader
      fragColor = vec4(vec3(Ia + Id + Is), 1.0);
    }
  </script>
  <canvas id="webgl-canvas">  </canvas>
```